# JPA Shopping Cart Program Issue

Tags: java, jpa

I am receiving the following error when running my JPA shopping cart.  I included the DBUtil and the Product DB code below:

```
type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class music.data.DBUtil
    music.data.ProductDB.selectProducts(ProductDB.java:57)
    music.admin.ProductAdminController.displayProducts(ProductAdminController.java:74)
    music.admin.ProductAdminController.doGet(ProductAdminController.java:36)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Here is the data.DBUtil:

```
package music.data;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class DBUtil {
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf =
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("productMaint2PU");

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEmFactory() {
        return emf;
    }
}
```

Here is the Product DB:

```
package music.data;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import music.business.Product;

public class ProductDB
{
    //This method returns null if a product isn't found.
    public static Product selectProduct(String productCode)
    {
      EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        String qString = "SELECT p FROM Product p " +
                "WHERE p.productCode = :productCode";
        TypedQuery<Product> q = em.createQuery(qString, Product.class);
        q.setParameter("productCode", productCode);
        try {
            Product product = q.getSingleResult();
            return product;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    //This method will return 0 if productID isn't found.
   // public static int selectProductID(Product product)


    //This method returns null if a product isn't found.
    public static Product selectProduct(int productID)
    {
        EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        String qString = "SELECT p FROM Product p " +
                "WHERE p.productID = :productID";
        TypedQuery<Product> q = em.createQuery(qString, Product.class);
        q.setParameter("productID", productID);
        try {
            Product product = q.getSingleResult();
            return product;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
      }

    //This method returns null if a product isn't found.
    public static List<Product> selectProducts()
    {
           EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        String qString = "SELECT p from Product p";
        TypedQuery<Product> q = em.createQuery(qString, Product.class);

        List<Product> products;
        try {
            products = q.getResultList();
            if (products == null || products.isEmpty())
                products = null;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return products;
    }    


//adds a new product
public static void insertProducts(Product product)
    {
        EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
        trans.begin();        
        try {
            em.persist(product);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            trans.rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

//updates the product
public static void updateProduct(Product product)
  {
   EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
        trans.begin();       
        try {
            em.merge(product);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            trans.rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

   //checks to see if the product exists
    public static boolean exists(String productCode) {
       Product p = selectProduct(productCode);   
        return p != null;
    }

    //removes the product
public static void removeProduct(Product product)
    {
      EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
        trans.begin();        
        try {
            em.remove(em.merge(product));
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            trans.rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }    
     }
}
```

If more code is needed, please let me know.

Here is the full stacktrace.  I know I am using the correct password and user b/c I have test these out on a different program that is working:

```
21-Nov-2015 11:01:06.784 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-126] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [productMaint2] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
21-Nov-2015 11:01:07.295 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-126] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/productMaint2]
21-Nov-2015 11:01:40.935 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-125] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\productMaint2.xml
21-Nov-2015 11:01:43.235 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-125] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\productMaint2.xml has finished in 2,300 ms
21-Nov-2015 11:01:43.250 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-128] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/productMaint2]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
[EL Info]: 2015-11-21 11:01:48.41--ServerSession(1856302541)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2015-11-21 11:01:48.72--ServerSession(1856302541)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Error Code: 1045
```

Comment: do a project clean and rebuild

Comment: so a class that DBUtil uses is not in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: It looks as if `music/data/DBUtil.class` is missing from your classpath. Is the above the full stacktrace?

Comment: How do I add it t the class path?

Comment: @Kenney NoClassDefFoundError != ClassNotFoundException. A dependency is missing, not that class